# Ultrasonic Sensor returns com3 false

Tags: arduino-nano

Im a very beginner with Arduino. Recently started with the blink code. Thats my only experience with these. Ive got an ultrasonic sensor (As in this tutorial http://howtomechatronics.com/tutorials/arduino/ultrasonic-sensor-hc-sr04/). So I setup the connections as trigger to Pin3 , Echo to 4, Vcc to 5v marked pin, GND to gnd next to 5v. Im using Arduino nano clone. When I run the program same as in the above example Im getting the following error. Other than that Im not getting any information.

[image]

Im sharing the same program I tried.

```
// defines pins numbers
const int trigPin = 3;
const int echoPin = 4;
// defines variables
long duration;
int distance;
void setup() {
pinMode(trigPin, OUTPUT); // Sets the trigPin as an Output
pinMode(echoPin, INPUT); // Sets the echoPin as an Input
Serial.begin(9600); // Starts the serial communication
}
void loop() {
// Clears the trigPin
digitalWrite(trigPin, LOW);
delayMicroseconds(2);
// Sets the trigPin on HIGH state for 10 micro seconds
digitalWrite(trigPin, HIGH);
delayMicroseconds(10);
digitalWrite(trigPin, LOW);
// Reads the echoPin, returns the sound wave travel time in microseconds
duration = pulseIn(echoPin, HIGH);
// Calculating the distance
distance= duration*0.034/2;
// Prints the distance on the Serial Monitor
Serial.print("Distance: ");
Serial.println(distance);
}
```

Comment: Where are you getting that error? That's not like any Arduino error I have ever seen.

Comment: I'm doing the code in Arduino web editor. I saw the above message in web console of the Arduino editor

Comment: That doesn't look like an error message - "level=info". I've never used the web editor but [this page](https://create.arduino.cc/projecthub/Arduino_Genuino/getting-started-with-the-arduino-web-editor-4b3e4a#toc-serial-monitor-6) says you need to open the sidebar to see the serial monitor. Did you do that?

Comment: @JohnnyMopp Thanks a lot for that. I was using wrong console window. I was using the plugin console instead of the web console by mistake. Thanks a lot for guiding the correct way